# Ajax solo devuelve lo que está en success una vez

Tags: javascript, ajax

Envío datos por POST con ajax y todo bien: la primera vez, hace lo que debe e imprime mensajitos de "Mensaje enviado", "espere" o "faltan campos por llenar".

La segunda vez que doy clic en el botón, vuelve a hacer todo bien a excepción de imprimir el div con los mensajes como alertas anteriormente mencionados.

Este es el input que hace de botón:

```
<input type="button" value="Enviar" id="EnviarCorreo">
```

Ajax:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).on('ready', function(){
  $('#EnviarCorreo').click(function() {
    var url = "enviarcorreo.php";
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        cache: false,
        url: url,
        data: $('#formcorreo').serialize(),
        beforeSend: function(){
          $('#enviado').html("Espere...");
        },
        success: function(data){
          $('#enviado').html(data);
          setTimeout("$('#enviado').fadeOut('fast');",1000) ;
        }
      });
  });

});
```

Aquí recibo los datos POST:

```
  if (!empty($_POST['correousuario']) ) {
      echo "¡Mensaje enviado!";
   } else {
    echo "Faltan campos por rellenar...";
   }
```

En este div es donde se muestran los resultados que el success "llama":

```
<div id="enviado"></div>
```

Pero como dije, solo muestra el mensaje en el div una vez, el segundo clic hace todo pero sin los mensajes en el div. Espero me haya explicado bien y que me puedan ayudar, se los agradeceré mucho.

Comment: Observación: sí tengo el cierre del script, (</script>) solo que se me pasó copiar y pegar bien.

Comment: Tras el primer success haces un fadeout, que equivale a añadirle un display:none al div, si no vuelves a mostrarlo en las siguientes veces no vas a verlo porque lo estás ocultando por css.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tras el primer success haces un `fadeOut` del `div`, que equivale a añadirle un `display:none` al `div`, si no vuelves a mostrarlo en las siguientes veces no vas a verlo porque lo estás ocultando por css. Sólo tienes que mostrarlo de nuevo en el `success`.

```
success: function(data){
          $('#enviado').html(data);
          $('#enviado').show();
          setTimeout("$('#enviado').fadeOut('fast');",1000) ;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Tras hacer un `fadeout`, al elemento con **id** enviado, este queda en `display: none` por lo que la segunda vez que pulsas el botón estás tratando de visualizar algo que está "oculto".

Una manera de solucionarlo sería poner al elemento en `display: block` justo después de inyectarle la respuesta que recibes en el `success`, de esta manera se mostrará durante un segundo antes de que salte el `fadeout` que tienes programado dentro del `setTimeout`.

**JQUERY**

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        cache: false,
        url: url,
        data: $('#formcorreo').serialize(),
        beforeSend: function(){
          $('#enviado').html("Espere...");
        },
        success: function(data){
          $('#enviado').html(data);
          $('#enviado').css('display', 'block');
          setTimeout("$('#enviado').fadeOut('fast');",1000) ;
        }
      });
```